# Delegates to check new data

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I need to check every 5 seconds if there is new data, and if yes, to fire up a delegate.

How to do this in simple and intuitive way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `Timer` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the Timer for this and use its tick event to be fired up

go through this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/how-to-use-timer-control-in-c
or

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could have your caller give the class with the timer a callback delegate to pass back the value

```
public class YourClass
{
    public static void Run(string address, Action<string> callback)
    {                     
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Elapsed += delegate {                         
            var response = callURL(address);

            callback(response);
        };          
        t.Interval = 5000;
        t.Start();                      
}


public class OtherClass
{
    public void ProcessResponse(string response)
    {
         // do whatever you want here to handle the response...
         // you can write it out, store in a queue, put in a member, etc.
    }


    public void StartItUp()
    {
         YourClass.Run("http://wwww.somewhere.net", ProcessResponse);
    }
}
```